# Вывод объекта в option или select Angular

Tags: angularjs, объекты, html-select

Здравствуйте. Имею переменную с объектом который содержит имя которое передается блоку, также параметры (список действий). Необходимость вывести параметры с помощью option или select.

//controller

```
$scope.dragObj = [{name:'Подписан через..',
                              properties:[{value: "Действие"},
                                          {value: "Действие"},
                                          {value: "Действие"},
                                          ]},
                               {name:'Ссылка кликнуть?',
                               properties:[{value: "Действие"},
                                          {value: "Действие"},
                                          {value: "Действие"},
                                          ]}, 
                               {name:'Письмо открыто?',
                                properties:[{value: "Действие"},
                                          {value: "Действие"},
                                          {value: "Действие"},
                                          ]}, 
                               {name:'Особый перевод',
                                properties:[{value: "Действие"},
                                          {value: "Действие"},
                                          {value: "Действие"},
                                          ]},
                               {name:'Изменено значение..',
                                properties:[{value: "Действие"},
                                          {value: "Действие"},
                                          {value: "Действие"},
                                          ]},
                               {name:'Письмо отправленно',
                                properties:[{value: "Действие"},
                                          {value: "Действие"},
                                          {value: "Действие"},
                                          ]},
                               ];
```

Отдельно вывести переменную в выпадающий список могу, вот чтоб вывести так cказать сабЗначение тут не получаеться. Спасибо.

Comment: какая итоговая разметка ожидается?

Comment: Блоки, каждый блок имеет свое имя полученное из name. при клике на блок необходимо чтоб значение properties менялось с выбранным блоком. Мне нужен шаблон того как это реализовать а дальше я сам уже размещу и сделаю.